# Color of PorterDuffXfermode on Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm using

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

to erase Paint on my canvas and it works exactly as expected, although it draws a black path of where I'm erasing until I let go, is there a way to make it clear?